# Resizing window skewes display (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making a program that bounces balls of the edge of its window, but I'm having issues with the bounds getting skewed.

If I set the initial resolution to a square window,

`int windowWidth  = 600;`

`int windowHeight = 600;`

it works fine. As soon as I reshape the window, the bounds on the window get skewed.

When it's square, it looks like this:
[image]

When I stretch it by its width, it looks like this:
[image]

When I stretch it by its height, it looks like this:
[image]

**Basically I'm not able to resize the window without skewing the bounds of the window.**

This is the code for my `reshape` function:

```
void reshape(GLsizei weight, GLsizei height)  
{ 
    if (height == 0) height = 1;               // To prevent divide by 0 
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)weight / height; // Get aspect ratio 

    // Set the viewport to cover the entire window 
    glViewport(0, 0, weight, height); 

    // Adjust the aspect ratio of clipping area to match the viewport 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Select the Projection matrix 
    glLoadIdentity();            // Reset 

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBalls; i++) 
    { 
        if (weight <= height)  
        { 
            balls[i].xLeft   = -1.0; 
            balls[i].xRight  = 1.0; 
            balls[i].yBottom = -1.0 / aspect; 
            balls[i].yTop    = 1.0 / aspect; 
        }  
        else 
        { 
            balls[i].xLeft   = -1.0 * aspect; 
            balls[i].xRight  = 1.0 * aspect; 
            balls[i]. yBottom = -1.0; 
            balls[i]. yTop    = 1.0; 
        } 
        gluOrtho2D(balls[i].xLeft, balls[i].xRight, balls[i].yBottom, balls[i].yTop); 
        balls[i].xPosMin = balls[i].xLeft + balls[i].ballRadius; 
        balls[i].xPosMax = balls[i].xRight - balls[i].ballRadius; 
        balls[i].yPosMin = balls[i].yBottom + balls[i].ballRadius; 
        balls[i].yPosMax = balls[i].yTop - balls[i].ballRadius; 
    } 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Select the model-view matrix 
    glLoadIdentity();           // Reset 
}
```

*Note: I can post more code if needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cut this from your loop:

```
gluOrtho2D(balls[i].xLeft, balls[i].xRight, balls[i].yBottom, balls[i].yTop);
```

and define your orthographic matrix once.

I think whenever your loop execute, you multiply a new matrix with previously inserted matrix in GL.

The produced orthographic matrix by GL is this:

[image]

Now when you set width: 800 and height: 600 your aspect ratio will be 1.33 and matrix for first loop will be:

[image]

Now by each loop, GL will multiply new matrix with previous matrix and coordinates will get closer by multiply each by 0.75.

(Also i am not sure)

Comment: @bames53 i don't know GL very well but glLoadIdentity() is out side of loop

Comment: Yeah, I saw after I commented and so deleted my comment.

Comment: Bringing glLoadIdentity() into the for loop fixed it. Thanks!